# Drupal form error redirect

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I need help for this problem:

In my Drupal 7 site i need to perform a redirect to a certain page if the login form is invalid, only in this occasion, and only for login form.
What is the best way to do this? what function is called?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean "redirect if user puts wrong values (username, password etc)?"

Comment: yes exactly, but only for login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add or alter the [#validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) options. Prefer the second method:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_user_login_form_validate';
 }
}

function MYMODULE_user_login_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
// Do some validation here. Better take the same codes from the validation functions below.
  if (...) {
   drupal_goto('CUSTOM_PATH');
  }
}
```

You can find the **validation functions** inside *ROOT/modules/user/user.module* file line 2113:

```
function user_login_default_validators() {
  return array('user_login_name_validate', 'user_login_authenticate_validate', 'user_login_final_validate');
}
```

Similar questions:

- (6.x, although it is the same) [Drupal Modify Login System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766337/drupal-modify-login-system)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form

Answer (score 0):

using hook_user_login method you can achieve the same,

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_user_login();
     */
    function MODULE_NAME_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
        $url = 'PAGE_TO_BE REDIRECTED';
        if (isset($user->uid) && $user->uid > 0) {
            drupal_goto($url);
        }
    }
```